# Access String Resource in AppWidget?

Tags: java, android

Normally, I'd do getString(R.string.myString), however it doesn't seem to work in a widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roger,

You may have to do something like the following:

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
String myString = res.getString(R.string.myString);
```

Answer (score 1):

`getString()` is in the [context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html), so you should get the context, and then call it. Can't quickly test it for you, but there's bound to be a getContext around somewhere :)